# How to install one single package listed on packages.debian.org?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, debian

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I really haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. Maybe my search terms weren't right.

So there is currently [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1649203) with the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, which is fixed in the version 3.6 of the package, which is [available in Debian jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) but not backported to Ubuntu. Apparently, one workaround for the issue is to use this version instead of the older version available in Ubuntu.

However, even if I was able to find the package listed on packages.debian.org, I couldn't find a way to install it! All that I could download from that webpage is the source file of the package. And I don't think I should directly add debian to my `/etc/apt/source.list` since that would make me install all other Debian packages as well.

How do I install this one single package?

---

EDIT: Apparently some people can't read. I mentioned explicitly in my question that the reason why I asked is that I couldn't find the package file on the page, only the source files. Now after reading the answer, I found the package file available for download at the bottom of the webpage, which was totally non-apparent at first sight.

Comment: Single .deb packages are installed after download by using `sudo dpkg -i <package>.deb`.

Comment: @ridgy OK. Apparently I overlooked the download link for the package file which is at the bottom of the page...

Comment: WOW. You are right. They've since then made it even harder to find the download link for the .deb... you can only get it by clicking the name of the package, which leads you to download instructions. There's not even a clear download link at the bottom of the page any more. I'm starting to think every single thing about linux is insane. I am now on like hour 9 of trying to figure out how to get the guest additions installed in my VM so I can just paste text into it. Hopefully the package I found will finally allow it.

Comment: Wow. It gets even better. Now dkpg is telling me that it can't install an amd64 because my architecture is i386. uname -r says my architecture is amd64. So I can't even manually install the .deb I just spent hours searching for a manual way to install. And now it's 4AM again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the dpkg package file , 
then run this command:
`sudo dpkg -i  --force-depends  your-package.dpkg`

The download link for the package file is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: OK. Apparently I overlooked the download link for the package file which is at the bottom of the page...